# How to deal with the crash in launch stage Android application?

Tags: android

When a crash happens on the launch stage of the Android application's main process (i.e. the process name is same as the application's package name), the application will crash, however, in most of the situation, there are multiple process running on the application, for example, :service or :otherprocess declare on the manifest.

After the crash and the main process have been killed, other application process or system_server is able to launch the main process again by starting a service or acquire a content provider. Then the main process will be started again, and will encounter the crash again.

Therefore, due to the process restart mechanism in the Android system, a application will enter a "crash loop".
which is: start the process -> crash -> restart by other process -> crash -> restart ...

This "crash loop" is able to happen on the background, there are two disadvantages:

1. consume lots of battery
2. report too much crash to the server, sometimes, one user can report thousands of crash items.

Google seems haven't solve this problem in the system_server side, how can we solve this and adapt the older version systems?

Comment: realistically, your app should just never crash :D

Comment: @a_local_nobody yep, but what if a unpredictable crash happen to user..

Comment: do you actually have a reproducible example of this ?